# Custom url for Azure web forms project to open specific .aspx page

Tags: c#, azure, webforms, azure-web-app-service

I have an Azure web forms project created and a custom url pointing to the .azurewebsites.net root. What I want to happen is when the custom url is entered, a specific .aspx page is called. Something to the effect of:

```
custom url (redirects) => blahblah.azurewebsites.net/login.aspx
```

I'm not sure if this would be a url rewrite scenario or what, but I'm not sure how to handle this in any case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your description, it seems you want to redirect unauthorized user to login.aspx page. I think it is more related with your application logic. Please try to configure your web.config with below code.

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
   <system.web>
      ...
      <authentication mode="Forms">
         <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="2880"/>
      </authentication>
      <authorization>
         <deny users="?"/>
      </authorization>
   </system.web>
</configuration>
```

If it is not meet your requirement, please write route/rewrite rule in your application.

Answer (score 0):

A custom domain name (e.g. `yourcustomname.com/`) is simply going to map to `yoursite.azurewebsites.net/`. If you want it going to somewhere specific (e.g. redirect to `login.aspx` from the default page, you'd have to create your own route / rewrite rule.